# Does Google Analytics 4 (GA4) have session unification?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Universal Analytics has a setting (toggle) to enable `session unification`. This allows for events fired prior to the user logging in to be associated with that user's session. (During log in the `Custom User Id (uid)` is provided to enable this.)

However, I am unable to find this feature on Google Analytics 4 (GA4). Is this feature enabled by default? Or is this no longer supported? I have read almost all GA4 documentation, but unfortunately it is still pretty limited at the time of writing this.

Thanks!

Comment: GA4 has mostly given up on the idea of sessions (even if some sessions KPIs have been added back, presumably due to user protest). It is focused on events and users instead. Conceptually it does not need session unification, since it does not have (or was not supposed to have) sessions.